# Execute a HTTP request within an app

Tags: android, html, hyperlink, arduino

I was wondering if I could make it open But NOT open the android browser, I just need it to visit: (pretend this is the ip) http;//91.91.91.91:2228?1, where it will trigger action on my arduino mega. I have tried to get it just to do this with this code

```
onclick(Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http;//91.9.91.91:?1");
    websiteIntent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(websiteIntent);)
```

but I don't know how to get it to do so

Comment: "make it open But NOT open the android browser"  Huh?

Comment: @Simon i know its too late, but i meant open in the app without opening the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A HttpClient will allow you to call an arbitrary URL within your app:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http;//91.9.91.91:?1");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Don't forget to wrap in a try catch though.

edit:

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http;//91.9.91.91:?1");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        }catch(Exception e){
            // Handle the exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry i am trying to get started with eclipse where do i put this?

Comment: Best bet would be to create a new Thread within your Activity. I've edited my answer to show this.

Comment: This has **NOTHING** to do with eclipse. It has to do with Java/Android programming.

Comment: Yup but the question is still valid, flag and edit exist for a reason.